# Не работает callback_query на webhook

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, callback, webhook

Не могу понять, почему не ловит callback_query клики по inline кнопке. Реагирует на любое сообщения в ботов. Присылает текст с inline кнопкой, но не реагирует на её нажатие. В терминал не выводит ничего

```
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from aiohttp import web
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, CallbackQuery

load_dotenv()
TOKENS = os.getenv('TOKEN').split(',')  
bots = {token: Bot(token=token) for token in TOKENS} 
dp = Dispatcher()
app = web.Application()  


async def set_all_webhooks():  
    for bot in bots.values():
        await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True) 
        webhook_uri = f'https://.....ngrok-free.app/{bot.token}'
        await bot.set_webhook(webhook_uri)


async def on_startup(app):  
    await set_all_webhooks()  


@dp.message()  
async def all_incoming(message: types.Message):
    await set(message)


async def set(message: types.Message):
    language_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'1', callback_data=f'5')]
    ])
    await message.answer(f'Нажми', reply_markup=language_kb)


@dp.callback_query()
async def click(callback: CallbackQuery):
    print(1)
    answer_data = callback.data
    await callback.answer(f'Значение кнопки {answer_data!r}')
    if answer_data == '5':
        text = 'Привет'
        await callback.message.answer(text)


async def handle_webhook(request):
    url = str(request.url)
    index = url.rfind('/')
    token = url[index + 1:]
    global check_token
    check_token = token

    if token in bots:
        request_data = await request.json()
        update = types.Update(**request_data)
        await dp._process_update(bot=bots[token], update=update)
        return web.Response()
    else:
        return web.Response(status=403)


for token in TOKENS:
    app.router.add_post(f"/{token}", handle_webhook)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.on_startup.append(on_startup)
    web.run_app(
        app,
        host='0.0.0.0',
        port=8080,
    )
```

pip list
Package            Version

---

aiofiles           23.1.0
aiogram            3.1.1
aiohttp            3.8.5
aiosignal          1.3.1
async-timeout      4.0.3
attrs              23.1.0
certifi            2023.7.22
charset-normalizer 3.3.0
frozenlist         1.4.0
idna               3.4
magic-filter       1.0.12
multidict          6.0.4
pip                23.2.1
pydantic           1.10.13
setuptools         65.5.0
typing_extensions  4.8.0
yarl               1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Переименованы декораторы **@dp.message()** и **@dp.callback_query()** в **@dp.message_handler()** и **@dp.callback_query_handler()**, чтобы соответствовать правильным именам декораторов в последней версии aiogram.

Использован метод **dp.process_updates** для обработки обновлений вместо прямого доступа к **_process_update**.

```
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from aiohttp import web
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, CallbackQuery

load_dotenv()
TOKENS = os.getenv('TOKEN').split(',')
bots = {token: Bot(token=token) for token in TOKENS}
dp = Dispatcher()
app = web.Application()

async def set_all_webhooks():
    for bot in bots.values():
        # Удаляем существующие вебхуки для каждого бота
        await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
        webhook_uri = f'https://.....ngrok-free.app/{bot.token}'
        # Устанавливаем новый вебхук для бота
        await bot.set_webhook(webhook_uri)

async def on_startup(app):
    await set_all_webhooks()

@dp.message_handler()
async def all_incoming(message: types.Message):
    await send_message(message)

async def send_message(message: types.Message):
    language_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'1', callback_data=f'5')]
    ])
    await message.answer(f'Нажми', reply_markup=language_kb)

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def click(callback: CallbackQuery):
    print(1)
    answer_data = callback.data
    await callback.answer(f'Значение кнопки {answer_data!r}')
    if answer_data == '5':
        text = 'Привет'
        await callback.message.answer(text)

async def handle_webhook(request):
    url = str(request.url)
    index = url.rfind('/')
    token = url[index + 1:]
    
    if token in bots:
        request_data = await request.json()
        update = types.Update(**request_data)
        await dp.process_updates([update])  # Используем dp.process_updates для обработки обновлений
        return web.Response()
    else:
        return web.Response(status=403)

for token in TOKENS:
    app.router.add_post(f"/{token}", handle_webhook)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.on_startup.append(on_startup)
    web.run_app(
        app,
        host='0.0.0.0',
        port=8080,
    )
```

Comment: В версии Aiogram 3+ :
Unresolved attribute reference 'process_updates' for class 'Dispatcher' 
Unresolved attribute reference 'callback_query_handler' for class 'Dispatcher' 
Unresolved attribute reference 'message_handler' for class 'Dispatcher'